# rbind function changing my entries

Tags: r

I have two data.frames that I want to append together. One data.frame holds past data, and the other data.frame holds future projected data. For example:

```
past <- structure(list(Period = c("2010-01-01", "2010-02-01", "2010-03-01", 
  "2010-04-01", "2010-05-01", "2010-06-01"), Count = c(3379221317, 
  3379221317, 3791458246, 4182424930, 4891432401, 5116360744)),
 .Names = c("Period", "Count"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

future <- structure(list(Period = structure(c(15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 
  15645, 15675), class = "Date"), Count = c(11051746713.9419, 11385578654.4160, 
  10864084232.2216, 11336164255.3271, 11121729107.9691, 12321341701.3780)),
  .Names = c("Period", "Count"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I used `rbind(past,future)` and for some reason the `Period` entries from the `future` data.frame are all renamed.  It looks like:

```
> rbind(past,future)
       Period       Count
1  2010-01-01  3379221317
2  2010-02-01  3379221317
3  2010-03-01  3791458246
4  2010-04-01  4182424930
5  2010-05-01  4891432401
6  2010-06-01  5116360744
7       15522 11051746714
8       15553 11385578654
9       15584 10864084232
10      15614 11336164255
11      15645 11121729108
12      15675 12321341701
```

Why are my dates renamed to random numbers?

Comment: How your data prints is not the same as how it's stored.  Please provide the results of running `dput(head(past))`, `dput(head(future))`, and `dput(head(rbind(past,future)))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from the output of `dput(past)`, `past$Period` is character, not a Date.  `str(past)` and `str(future)` would have shown you they were different.

```
> str(past)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Period: chr  "2010-01-01" "2010-02-01" "2010-03-01" "2010-04-01" ...
 $ Count : num  3.38e+09 3.38e+09 3.79e+09 4.18e+09 4.89e+09 ...
> str(future)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Period: Date, format: "2012-07-01" "2012-08-01" ...
 $ Count : num  1.11e+10 1.14e+10 1.09e+10 1.13e+10 1.11e+10 ...
```

All the elements in the column of a data.frame must be the same type, so the `future$Period` column gets converted... not sure why it doesn't get converted correctly though, since:

```
> as.character(future$Period)
[1] "2012-07-01" "2012-08-01" "2012-09-01" "2012-10-01"
[5] "2012-11-01" "2012-12-01"
```

So the solution is to *either*:

1. covert `future$Period` to character: `future$Period <-
   as.character(future$Period)`
2. covert `past$Period` to Date: `past$Period <-
   as.Date(past$Period)`

depending on your desired output.

Comment: Thanks, how did you figure out the datastructure was character from the output I gave? Did you just try to recreate it in R?

Comment: @RayJTong: I couldn't tell that `Period` was character from your original question, which is why I asked for the output from `dput`.  `dput` creates a text representation of an R object that you can copy/paste into an R session.  If you look carefully at the output of `str(future)`, you can see `Period` is "chr".

Answer (score 3):

They are not random. Matrix elements are required to have no attributes, so factors, Dates and POSIXt items become their numeric representations if coerced to matrices. There is an `rbind.data.frame` but you have apparently offered `rbind` an object that ended up calling the non-data.frame version of that function. You will need to offer dput() from both arguments to get a better answer.

Comment: structure(list(Period = c("2010-01-01", "2010-02-01", "2010-03-01", "2010-04-01", "2010-05-01", "2010-06-01") 

structure(list(Period = structure(c(15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675), class = "Date") 

Seems like the second one is wrapped around another structure(). Anyway to normalize it?

Comment: One of those is a character vector and the other is a Date-classed vector.